# async return to client side asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous, task

I have web app with asp.net web forms, there is a button that makes a postback.
Event handler of this button executes in cycle some operations and on each iteration it makes html. How can I return this hmlm to the client on every iteration

```
public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs)
{
    foreach(var item in some_collection)
    {
        Var html = generateHtml();
        //here i want to return html to client and add to dom
    }
}
```

How can I redesign this method? Maybe use tasks, async or something else?

UPDATE: I've decided to use ASP.NET SignalR. It's very powerful framework to solve my problem

Comment: You can't... Read more about http protocol. You may also try to use WebSockets....

Comment: I think about usingsockets.thank you

Comment: websocket is not supported in old browsers, and many host providers don't support it as well. Even if they do, the number of connection is usually limited to < 50 - 100. So take those into consideration.

Comment: @Steve there are open source js libraries when browser doesn't support HTML5 they fall back to flash to support WebSockets. BTW: I have a server that handles 1000s of clients concurrently. So, Those are not limitations to use WebSockets. But of course, It is a matter of taste.

Comment: @L.B you do realize the fall back uses long pulling or infinite script right? This would kill your thread pool very quickly

Comment: @Steve I don't say anything hypothetically, I wrote it and it works in production...

Comment: @L.B well~~ I am just trying to point out the down side of that. since I would never recommend doing so. sry for my wording if it sounds offensive to you.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't. Http is stateless meaning that it throws away all the user's connection information once it is done sending back the result. Your best bet would be to make some Web API methods and use javascript ajax call to retrieve the html. If you want to include user specific information/settings then include those in the cookie